# Separating localStorage local namespace

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

This is probably the first time I run into this issue. LocalStorage is linked to the domain – e.g. domain.com, another.com, last.com. If I were to locally develop these websites, I might run them all on port 5000, provided I run only one website at a time. What I noticed though is that accessing `localStorage.getItem('test')` from these domains will make them share this piece of storage space since for browser, it's all one property. Is there anything I can do to avoid this issue apart from running the local environment on a different port or prefixing/suffixing the key names?

Comment: Ports are considered part of the domain name.  Simply use a different port for each project and they will no longer share the same local storage.

Comment: Thank you @Archer!

Comment: No problem - nice and simple :)